# KeyFrame Animation doesn't execute

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm taking a course, and I'm getting to the @keyframe level. I'm trying to test this code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MehdiX/pen/mdywMzY?editors=1100).

But unfortunately it does not work, nothing happens as you can see. I opted for an error in my code since I did a test on my PC and still nothing.

**My HTML :**

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="btn">Click Here !</div>
  <div class='progress'>
    <div class="progress__bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My SCSS :**

```css
.btn {
  background-color:pink;
  width:20%;
  padding:10px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-bottom:2rem;
  &:active {
    & > .progress__bar {
      animation:progress-bar 1000ms;
    }
  }
}

.progress {
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}

.progress__bar {
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  margin-top:2px;
  transform:scaleX(0);
}

@keyframes progress-bar {
  0% {
    transform:scaleX(0);
  } 
  100% {
    transform:scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

*The weird thing is that on Jsfiddle it doesn't work either.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `>` CSS combinator in the CSS rules for your button. This works only if the progress bar is a child of the button, but it's not - it's a sibling of the button. You can make this work using the `~` sibling combinator:

```css
&:active {
  & ~ .progress .progress__bar {
    animation:progress-bar 1000ms;
  }
}
```